# NSAlert beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:

Tags: cocoa

While setting up an `NSAlert` object to be displayed as a modal sheet in Xcode 5.0.2, I hit an interesting surprise.

I was planning on using `beginSheetModalForWindow:modalDelegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:`

As I started to enter it, Xcode autofilled `beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:` for me (even though I cannot find this in any `NSAlert` documentation).

I prefer to use completion handlers rather than delegate/selector as a callback mechanism, so I went  ahead and tried it. I was pleasantly surprised to find that it worked perfectly.

Three quick questions before I commit to this.

1. Am I missing something in the documentation?
2. Is it "safe" to use this feature if it is undocumented?  *(i.e. will it magically disappear as mysteriously as it appeared?)*
3. I'd rather not hardcode the response values based on what I'm seeing via logging.  Does anybody know the "proper" `NS...Button` constants?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This call is “safe” but it’s 10.9+ only. Here it is from the header file:

```
#if NS_BLOCKS_AVAILABLE
- (void)beginSheetModalForWindow:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow completionHandler:(void (^)(NSModalResponse returnCode))handler NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9);
#endif
```

It appears they just accidentally left it out of the current docs. The headers are generally considered the “truth” in Cocoa, though—they authoritatively tell you what’s deprecated and what’s new. (Unlike in X11, for instance, where the documentation was declared to be correct over the actual implementations or the headers.)

These are the constants you want to use inside your completionHandler block:

```
/* These are additional NSModalResponse values used by NSAlert's -runModal and -beginSheetModalForWindow:completionHandler:.

   By default, NSAlert return values are position dependent, with this mapping:
       first (rightmost) button = NSAlertFirstButtonReturn
       second button = NSAlertSecondButtonReturn
       third button = NSAlertThirdButtonReturn
       buttonPosition 3+x = NSAlertThirdButtonReturn + x

   Note that these return values do not apply to an NSAlert created via +alertWithMessageText:defaultButton:alternateButton:otherButton:informativeTextWithFormat:, which instead uses the same return values as NSRunAlertPanel.  See NSAlertDefaultReturn, etc. in NSPanel.h
*/
enum {
    NSAlertFirstButtonReturn    = 1000,
    NSAlertSecondButtonReturn   = 1001,
    NSAlertThirdButtonReturn    = 1002
};
```

Comment: I'm building on a machine running 10.9, but have specified 10.6 as the deployment target.   Does this mean that when I finally get around to testing on a 10.6 machine that this will fail?

Comment: Yah, you’ll have to use the older methods for 10.6 or it’ll crash. It’s silly there’s no warning when you use methods that are “too new” but that was their decision.